# MySQL - Set trigger BEFORE INSERT for new ID is safe?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

How to create customize primary key in MySQL?, example i have table and the table name is `X`, I have a table field as `ID`,`Code`,`Name`.

> I am afraid **if I have 1000 users** and when they input together will
>   **result in destruction**

and i want to :

```
INSERT INTO `X` (`ID`,`Code`,`Name`) VALUES 
('P3K','Alex'), // this primary key is "P3K-1"
('SOS','Force'), // this primary key is "SOS-1"
('P3K','Bash'), // this primary key is "P3K-2"
```

Right now, i using TRIGGER (*BEFORE INSERT*) for this, like this one:

```
SET NEW.`ID` = CONCAT(NEW.`Code`,'-',IFNULL(SUBSTRING_INDEX((
  SELECT `x`.`Code` FROM `X` WHERE 
    X.`Code` = NEW.`Code` and 
ORDER BY X.`Code` DESC
LIMIT 1 ),'-',-1),0) + 1))
```

I did not try this code, but my point is:

1. User insert
2. Before insert I checking LAST Primary
3. IF Null then i set 0, else i cut the symbol (-) and take the last part
4. I increments (using [+ 1])
5. Final, i concat `CODE` and New Number.

am i misguided? LOL, and if true, how to create like this one?
**(I THINK)** We can do it and **maybe** no one knows about this, how does AI in MySQL work so perfectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not make `auto_increment` any column you want to manipulate explicitly. That can confuse an engine and cause serious problems. If no column you have used for primary key are `auto_increment` you can do anything you want with them via triggers. Sure generated values will be rejected if they violate the mandatory uniqness of the primary key.